# How to center element in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, mobile

I have an input element that width is 20% and I want to center it horizontally. I have tried text-align center (parent element), but it didn't help. Here how it looks (the input box):

[image]

now the element code is like this:

```
<fieldset class="ui-grid-solo" style="text-align:center !important;">
   <input type="number" class="answerIput"/>
</fieldset>
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `margin: 0 auto` to the element.  With a fixed-width block element, automatic left/right margins will center it relative to the parent:

```
<input type="number" class="answerIput" style="margin: 0 auto;">
```

Answer (score 2):

use margins

```
<input type="number" class="answerIput" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;" />
```